# Can an admission webhook control the admission of admission webhooks?

Tags: kubernetes

Attempting this suggests that it's not possible (handlers aren't triggered) but I've been unable to find errors.

E.g.:

```
apiVersion: admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: ValidatingWebhookConfiguration
metadata:
  name: webhook
webhooks:
- name: webhook.example.com
  rules:
  - apiGroups:
    - admissionregistration.k8s.io
    apiVersions:
    - v1
    operations:
    - CREATE
    - UPDATE
    - DELETE
    resources:
    - mutatingwebhookconfigurations
    - validatingwebhookconfigurations
    clientConfig:
      url: https://ENDPOINT/validate
    admissionReviewVersions:
    - v1
    sideEffects: None
```

For simplicity, I deployed a basic Go HTTP server (with `/mutate`, `/validate` and `/readyz` handlers) to Google Cloud Run and substituted the service's `ENDPOINT` in the above config.

I wrote a simple (`book`) CRD and created a second `ValidatingWebhookConfiguration` for the `book` resource using the **same** Webhook implementation (the same Cloud Run service).

When I CRUD `book` Resources, the Webhook endpoints are correctly invoked (logged by the webhook) so I know that the Webhook configuration is correct and the implementation works.

When I CRUD the `book`'s `ValidatingWebhookConfiguration`, the handler isn't invoked and I'm unable to find anything logged by Kubernetes.

I've tried using both MicroK8s (v1.27) and Google Kubernetes Engine (v1.27) and conclude that it's not possible.

The API server includes metrics (for the `books` CRD and for some GKE-specific CRDs but nothing for `*webhookconfigurations`):

```
apiserver_admission_webhook_request_total{code="200",name="books.example.com",operation="CREATE",rejected="false",type="validating"} 7
apiserver_admission_webhook_request_total{code="200",name="books.example.com",operation="DELETE",rejected="false",type="validating"} 4
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by that? Maybe there is a better way.

Comment: I would like to be able to control the admission of admission webhooks so as to be able to control these being added|deleted to clusters

Comment: You would normally do that using rbac. Only those who should be able to add and delete them get a role that contains the rights to do so.